# AsRock b450 steel legend no post, no beep, no display, after working properly

Tags: boot, memory, graphics-card, bios, motherboard

I have bought the b450 steel legend in combination with the AMD Ryzen 5 5600G.

Including two memory sticks of 8GB each I had the build working.

To prepare the system for windows 11 I only had to enable the secure boot.

After some reading I tried the option 'enable EUFI boot' and I was playing around with 'fast boot'.

Now, after saving the settings I rebooted the system and that's when nothing worked any more.

The fans on my MB, and green LEDs do work.

After trying to enter the BIOS I figured I'd do a reset, since I expected the system to go to the state I initially received.

After reading, I did the following to reset the BIOS:

1. Remove any cables from the computer (power, HDMI, etc)
2. Connect the jumper switch (part 19 on the design overview)
3. Hold the power button for 30 seconds
4. Remove the CMOS battery
5. Wait for 5 minutes (tried a couple of times, waiting 10 minutes and 12 hours)
6. Inserted battery
7. Removed jumper connection
8. Restarted system

Now after that, the system doesn't do anything, except for fans that run and lights that shine.

There is no display on screen, not over MB not over GFX.

Using a GFX card, or have none installed, no difference.

- I have two 8GB RAM cards, tried in any combination over the slots, nothing
- Used only one card, tried all slots, nothing. Not even with the other memory card.
- I tried the debug speaker, but no sound there. After i did a faulty installation of the RAM, the 3 beeps as expected worked. There was no other signal after correctly installing the RAM.

I am out of options.

One thing i now feel bad about, is that jumping the system (resetting the bios), affected the BIOS version, so the CPU is not supported any more? I know this is a very far stretch, but I have no clue for any other options.

How can I get out of this boot issue? Especially when everything worked fine before I tried playing with EUFI and fast boot?

Comment: Does the board have BIOS Flashback option? i.e. to update Firmware (BIOS/UEFI)without CPU using external pen drive directly thru flashback USB port. If so try updating the BIOS.  Ideally after resetting the CMOS settings it should go back to lowermost defaults and start all over again. If everything else fails, consider board RMA.

Comment: Can assure you, nothing you did "affected the BIOS version" - except if you actually flashed the BIOS yourself and forgot to mention it - perhaps you've connected the front panel connectors wrong (shorted the reset for example) - try connecting ONLY the power switch to the FP connector

Comment: patkim Unfortunately i cannot find any flashback options, only isntantflash that requirs access to the bios.
JaromandaX i did not flash it myself, could this be done by the manufacturer? That i removed this by the CMOS reset?
Using only the power connector did not change the behavior unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pure hardware failure.
The CPU, Motherboard and RAM got replaced for identical types and everything works fine.